# Laravel project redirect to other laravel project on same ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, server

I am newbie for laravel and Ubuntu server. I have problem with laravel project. I have 2 laravel projects folder on same server (Ubuntu 14.04), 
one of project will redirect to other project and whenever I restart server it will switch to other project ( I used subdomain for both projects )

ex. Project A / Project B

- aaa.domain.com -> Project A
- bbb.domain.com -> Project A

after restart server

- aaa.domain.com -> Project B
- bbb.domain.com -> Project B

**my conf files**

**Project A**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin name@domain.com
    ServerName aaa.domain.com
    ServerAlias aaa.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aaa/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Project B**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin name@domain.com
    ServerName bbb.domain.com
    ServerAlias bbb.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bbb/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I've tried to put only index.php file (only echo something) on one of project, It's work normally, not sure where I was config wrong or forgot something?

Please give me some advise. Thank you.

Comment: check your `.htaccess` file. there could be some redirect rule sitting and doing the redirect

Comment: Thank you @Cerlin Boss, both of my .htaccess are as the following, no redirect to anything

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : `/etc/apache2/sites-available` goto this path with sudo and `cp 000-default.conf aaa.conf` run this command. here aaa.conf will be generate newly.

Step 2 : Open "aaa.conf" file `gedit aaa.conf`

Step 3 : Set  Server name `ServerName aaa.domain.com` Remove comment it is there and set Docuement Root Path too. `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aaa` save and exit.

Step 4 : Then run this command `a2ensite aaa.conf` it will generate one file at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` here with same name.

Step 5 : Then `gedit /etc/hosts` open this file and `127.0.0.1  aaa.domain.com` this line below `127.0.0.1  localhost`

Step 6 : Restart Server `service apache2 restart`

Same for Project B too.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I've deleted the old .conf files and copy the new one from 000-default.conf  and change according to your suggest but still the same

Comment: It's working fine for me. can you provide me you 000-default.conf file..